# Adding Carbon numbers to bonds in Newman figure

Tags: chemistry

Can anyone please help me in making this graph?

I went through the process of making Newman figure, but unable to give numbers to nodes within it like the image I have pasted:

[image]

### Edit by ManuelKuehner -- copy and paste of the comment of the OP

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mhchem} 
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\chemsetup{modules=newman} 
\begin{document} 
\newman{\hspace*{3mm} 
\ce{CH3},H,H,\hspace*{3mm} \ce{CH3},H,H} \
end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please tell me how to make this figure! I went through the starter guide, and there is nothing that helped me draw the figure i have shown above.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics) is what you need. [This](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) is the package. Give it a try, and if you still have troubles, come back, showing what you have tried and why it does not work.

Comment: The starter guide doesn't concern how to do your figure, it concerns how to ask a question in a way that can be easily answered. In particular, please edit your post and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @luchonacho Newman projections are not really possible with `chemfig`! In general I'd just draw them with TikZ

Comment: In your question you ask to add the numbers - this implies that you know how to do the drawing itself. Please add your code for the drawing, I'm sure we then can help you to add the numbers. If this interpretation of your question is incorrect, please change it accordingly.

Comment: @samcarter I suspect the OP might use the macros from the `chemmacros` package with which adding the numbers would indeed be difficult... Hence my suggestion to use TikZ. But this is actually only guesswork so...

Comment: Yes, Following is the code I am using to make the following figure: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=newman}
\begin{document}
\newman{\hspace*{3mm} \ce{CH3},H,H,\hspace*{3mm} \ce{CH3},H,H}
\end{document}

@clemens

Comment: Can any one please help on this??? I am still waiting for help. I have put my MWE in above comment

Answer (score 3):

Worst case: you could manually add the numbers, for example using a picture environment.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\chemsetup{modules=newman} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{picture}(80,80)
\put(0,0){\newman{\hspace*{3mm}\ce{CH3},H,H,\hspace*{3mm}\ce{CH3},H,H}}
\put(20,75){1}
\put(32,29){2}
\put(38,40){3}
\end{picture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this dosent solve my troubles. I need to add the following image to my question paper. And because of picture environment it is not properly alinged.

Comment: @AbhijeetPattnayak If you would add a MWE to your questions that shows how the alignment should be, I am sure the above code can be adapted.

Comment: I have already added 2 days ago, i will do it again here : 
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mhchem} \usepackage{chemmacros} \chemsetup{modules=newman} \begin{document} \newman{\hspace*{3mm} \ce{CH3},H,H,\hspace*{3mm} \ce{CH3},H,H} \end{document}

Comment: @AbhijeetPattnayak But you don't show how the alignment should be changed.

Comment: I am not sure. I dont even understand this set of coding. Can you help create a working using chemistry packages. I need to put it in chemistry packages